# Powershell does not recognize invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I am unable to use invoke-sqlcmd in powershell. I've loaded the module written by Chad Miller as described here: [Problems using SQL Server 2008 R2 PowerShell extensions outside of SQLPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820591/problems-using-sql-server-2008-r2-powershell-extensions-outside-of-sqlps)

The module loads just fine without error, and using get-module shows sqlps as expected. However, using get-pssnapin does not show either SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 or SqlServerProviderSnapin100

When I type invoke-sqlcmd I get the error "The term 'invoke-sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program..."

Running Windows 7 Pro, have SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008R2, have installed SQL Server 2008R2 Management Objects.

Thanks for any help
Jon

Comment: When you run Get-PSSnapin are you using the -registered switch?  Otherwise, it's only going to show you the snapins that are already loaded.

Comment: Using the -registered switch returns nothing.

Comment: Is the snapin bit-specific? Are you trying this from a 64-bit PowerShell prompt? If so, try an x86 prompt.

Comment: Rookie mistake - the module was unsigned and I had execution policy set to remotesigned - all better now. Running the install with verbose turned on caught it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, the module was located in my profile which was on a network share - that doesn't work either. Needs to be physically on the same box.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem:)
This what i did:
Register dll from sql files:

```
set-alias installutil $env:windir\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\installutil
installutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSProvider.dll"
installutil -i "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\Redist\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PSSnapins.dll"
```

Then you can check by:
get-PSSnapin -registered

and now add snapins:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100   
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

That works for me. Hope it helps...

Sorry for my english:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case,  this issue was solved installing Microsoft® Windows PowerShell Extensions for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 and Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Shared Management Objects both included in  Microsoft® SQL Server® Feature Pack

Download link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065