# invoke-sqlcmd not working on few machines even with all prerequisite msi installed

Tags: powershell

Hi I have been having some issues getting invoke-sqlcmd working from one of my machines. I followed these instructions: [Problems using SQL Server 2008 R2 PowerShell extensions outside of SQLPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820591/problems-using-sql-server-2008-r2-powershell-extensions-outside-of-sqlps)

I also installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295 SharedManagementObjects and PowershellTools using DSC and confirmed in output
 that it's installed. But when I tried to add it using:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100
```

It throws an error message that

> SqlServerCmdLetsnapin100 and SqlServerProviderSnapin100  are not
>   installed on the computer

I also tried importing sqlps module.  The machine I'm having this issue on is Win 2012 R2.

Thanks

Note: This is happening randomly on a few machines. We need the sql provider snap  installed on all machines.

Comment: For anyone looking,Someone answered on twitter.
Proving full path works ..https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx

Import-Module -Name c:\ps-test\modules\test -Verbose

Comment: You can answer your own question--please either answer it or delete the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Tony, It didn't let me answer the question, it threw an error that I cannot answer my question, that's why I posted it as a comment. HTH

Answer (score 0):

[Credit to OP for answer in comments]

Providing the full path to the module resolved the issue.  Please see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849725.aspx

`Import-Module -Name c:\ps-test\modules\test -Verbose`